# MySQL nearest results - PHP geolocation loop issues

Tags: php, sql, gps, geolocation, coordinates

This is my php code..

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('','','','');

$lat = "40.3828192";
$lon = "10.7234345";

$check = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * ,(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( 
POWER(SIN(($lat    - mlat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( $lat * pi()/180) *
COS(mlat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( $lon - mlon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )))
AS distance FROM org HAVING distance < 50 ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 100");

$rowi = mysqli_fetch_array($check);

if ($rowi == 0) {       
echo "No results nearby!"; 
} 
else {
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($check))
{
$distance= $row['distance'] * 60 * 1852;
echo $row['oname']; echo " - "; echo $distance; echo "<br>";
    };
};

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

**The problem I am having is that the duplicate results in a loop do not show.. I am currently trying to display all the database rows by the order of nearest.. I have currently 4, but only 3 are showing since 2 of them have the same coordinates..**

Is there a way too display all rows even though some have the same coordinates and with that the same distance... I am also not sure that the distance in meters is correct.. I have 60NM for each degree and 1852 for conversion from NM..

**The actual issue is that the first row which has the same coordinates as we are checking against ($lat,$lon) doesn't list out.. When checking for other rows (copied) with the same coordinates they are correctly returned with a distance 0.. Where is the problem?**

Comment: You can do all the mathematical calculations by using php and ignore the calculations from the query for good performance.

Comment: What do you mean.. Limit the acceptable distance coordinates before calling query? Do you have an example?

Comment: https://www.marketingtechblog.com/calculate-distance/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have used fetch array twice, first to check it and then to list out rows.. That's way the first row was missing.. I have replaced it with num_rows and it works now..

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('','','','');

$lat = "40.3828192";
$lon = "10.7234345";

$check = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * ,(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( 
POWER(SIN(($lat    - mlat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( $lat * pi()/180) *
COS(mlat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( $lon - mlon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )))
AS distance FROM org HAVING distance < 50 ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 100");

$rowi = mysqli_num_rows($check);

if ($rowi == 0) {       
echo "No results nearby!"; 
} 
else {
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($check))
{
$distance= $row['distance'] * 60 * 1852;
echo $row['oname']; echo " - "; echo $distance; echo "<br>";
    };
};

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

However, I am stil not sure about moving location calculation to php and out of sql query.. Does anyone have a simple solution?